# Sort array by sub-values from JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

```
{
   "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
   "name": "Taric's Enforcers",
   "entries": [
      {
         "leaguePoints": 502,
         "isFreshBlood": false,
         "isHotStreak": true,
         "rank": "I",
         "leagueName": "Taric's Enforcers",
         "isInactive": false,
         "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
         "isVeteran": true,
         "tier": "CHALLENGER",
         "lastPlayed": -1,
         "playerOrTeamName": "CaliforniaTrlolz",
         "playerOrTeamId": "21059607",
         "wins": 155
      },
      {
         "leaguePoints": 478,
         "isFreshBlood": false,
         "isHotStreak": false,
         "rank": "I",
         "leagueName": "Taric's Enforcers",
         "isInactive": false,
         "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
         "isVeteran": false,
         "tier": "CHALLENGER",
         "lastPlayed": -1,
         "playerOrTeamName": "Knives Millions",
         "playerOrTeamId": "21088719",
         "wins": 116
      },
```

I have this long json data, and I need it sorted by the "leaguePoints" key value from highest to lowest. I have used json_decode set to true to place the entire json into a PHP-ready associative array, but I cannot get it sorted by the value "leaguePoints". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what efforts you have made to sort this?  Why aren't they working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
usort($array['entries'], function($a, $b) {
    return $b['leaguePoints'] - $a['leaguePoints'];
});
```

Demo here - http://ideone.com/RTlxc3

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I put it slightly different, as an actual function instead of inline, but this worked perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for.